# Drift velocity question

Tags: electricity, solid-state-physics

I'm studying about Drude's model. Given that τ is the average time between the electrons' collisions with the ions and the applied electric field is E, we have: 
$$a=\frac{eE}{m_e}$$ where e is the electron charge and me the electron mass. We know that for an accelerating movement the change in speed is given by : $$Δv=at=>\\Δu=\frac{eE}{m_e}t$$ Now if we substitute t with τ we get what's called drift velocity. $$u_d=\frac{eE}{m_e}τ=μE$$ My textbook says the following :

> In a time interval t each electron moves a distance $$u_dt$$

Shouldn't he have used : $$Δx=\frac{1}{2}at^2$$ since the drift velocity is not the average velocity?

Comment: have a look http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html

Comment: The diffusion velocity averages out to zero. The drift (field induced) does not. Please clarify your confusion.

Comment: @Sorry for my rusty English. In an accelerating movement , to find the distance covered we multiply the time by the average speed. However, the author didn't do this here. Ud is given by acceleration times τ, which gives the average speed before every collision and not the average speed while the electron is travelling until the collision.

Comment: @JonCuster I hope it's more clear now, I edited the question.

Comment: Can you upload an image of the text related to this derivation? It would be useful to see how the textbook is handling this topic.

Comment: Possibly relevant : [Drift velocity in Drude model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/323959)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drift velocity in Drude model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323959/drift-velocity-in-drude-model)